# Where are glGenVertexArrays & glBindVertexArrays in Qt 5.1?

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm using Qt 5.1 and I can't find these functions and I try to look at here

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglfunctions.html

they don't appear in the list, or they don't exist in the Qt?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglfunctions-3-1.html ?

Comment: Do you know how to use it. I try to include this header and make an instance of it but it doesn't work.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" How can we possibly help you with that description of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in reading [this tutorial](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/).

It explains how to set up OpenGL with Qt 5.1, and most notably in part 2, how to use Vertex Array Objects. You have to create them using the "object-oriented" wrapper class `QOpenGLVertexArrayObject` instead of calling the raw C-style OpenGL functions.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Don't inherit from `QOpenGLFunctions`, inherit version 3 or later. If you're following along with https://learnopengl.com/, then use `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core`.

Explanation :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-module.html
"The QOpenGLFunctions class provides cross-platform access to the OpenGL ES 2.0 API."
glGenVertexArrays & glBindVertexArrays are only introduced in version 3. That's why inheriting from QOpenGLFunctions doesn't give you them.